# Stop WebStorm from folding html elements

Tags: webstorm, folding

This has really been bugging me now that someone pointed it out. WebStorm has been folding up `&nbsp;` I'm sure some people like this but I would rather always see these html elements.

Here is a picture of what I'm talking about.

[image: example of folded html element]

You can see the green carrot which represents the folded code and since I'm hovering over it in this picture you can see the tool tip that shows it unfolded.

Can anyone point me to a switch to shut this off?

Comment: Interesting: I have a HTML file full of entities (including this one) but do not see them folded by default. In any case -- if it's folded by default (and you did nothing to make it like that .. which right now I doubt as you have another one on your screenshot which looks normal) .. then try `Settings/Preferences | Editor | General | Code Folding | XML entities`

Comment: so a note on that. The other is shown because I clicked on it before taking that screen shot. If you click them they will open and stay open.. seemingly for a while? If I close the file and come back it will still be open but if I come back say the next day its collapsed again. Also I have tried turning off the xml entities default

Comment: @LazyOne Curious if you are on the latest version too? I'm running 2016.2 162.1121.31

Comment: I've tested that using PhpStorm 2016.2.1 EAP build 162.1447.5 . I'm not aware of any other option -- maybe devs themselves know. It's also possible (although pretty unlikely) that it's done by some additional plugin (which I do not have).

Answer (score 3):

@LazyOne got it correct. Here is the screenshot in 2016.3
[image]

FYI Many of these are checked by default. So I suspect new users coming from other editors may want to uncheck them all until they get a better handle on the program.